# Why does my socket module yield no attributes?

Tags: python, sockets

None of the attributes in the socket module are callable. I ran the following and I list the output below. Why is this happening?

```
import socket 
print dir(socket)
```

--

```
python testr.py
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', 'socket']
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', 'socket']
```

Comment: Do you have a script named `socket.py` or maybe a folder named `socket`?

Comment: I initially titled the script socket.py then deleted when I knew of error. Just realized I still had byte code file, deleted and solved the problem. Thanks @KevinGuan!